# dealing with list and messages in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, message

very new here, but i am inviting 3 people to dinner and i have to send each of them a message from a list inviting them to dinner.. I am at the beginning and i have

```
dinnerGuest = ['Steve Jobs', 'Tupac Shakur', 'Kobe Bryant']
message = """You have been cordially invited to an epic dinner.
Please RSVP as soon as possible. Thank you""" + dinnerGuest[0].title + "."
print(message)
```

I get the error

```
Please RSVP as soon as possible. Thank you""" + dinnerGuest[0].title + "."
TypeError: Can't convert 'builtin_function_or_method' object to str implicitly
```

ANYONE KNOW WHY?  Thanks in advance and I know this is a novice question. I shall get there though.

Comment: I have a feeling only Kobe Bryant will be showing up to that dinner party..

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Comment: yes it is. thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

```
dinnerGuest = ['Steve Jobs', 'Tupac Shakur', 'Kobe Bryant']
message = """You have been cordially invited to an epic dinner.
Please RSVP as soon as possible. Thank you""" + dinnerGuest[0].title() + "."
print(message)
```

title() is a function - it takes something and turns it into something else.

Whenever you use a function, always put parentheses at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to invite all the guests present in the list, So you will have to traverse through the whole list using a loop:

```
dinnerGuest = ['Steve Jobs', 'Tupac Shakur', 'Kobe Bryant']

message = """You have been cordially invited to an epic dinner. 
              Please RSVP as soon as possible. Thank you """

for i in dinnerGuest:
    print(message + i.title() + ".")
```

Also as mentioned by @Andrew Owen and @Francisco Couzo, you need to use **title()** instead of **title** as it is a method and requires () after it.